# Open Specific dir with fileInput Shiny R

Tags: r, file-io, upload, shiny, directory

Is there any way to open the default Windows Images folder with the `fileInput` component?

Right now it is opening "My Computer" and I don't want this behaviour.

Comment: would you like to open a file within a specific folder or would you like to change the starting point of your `fileInput`?

Comment: Change the starting directory

Comment: Don't think it's possible. But you could circumvent the problem with `selectInput` and `choices=list.files(your_folder, full.names=TRUE)`.

Comment: This is weird. A while ago it was opening "Documents" and now it's opening "My Computer". Why would it change? I'll try that.

Comment: Perhaps that's related with your explorer (eg the last place where you selected a file or something like thos), not with shiny

Comment: Nope, fileInput doesn't have a choices parameter. This should be added in future releases to improve user experience.

Comment: `selectInput` not `fileInput`. you'll pick one file (path), then you still have to import it.

Comment: `list.files` will only list files/folders on the server, not on the client (i.e. your computer). I don't think there is anything Shiny can do here. The default location is determined by Windows.

Comment: This works for me. I only use Shiny for the interface, not the client/server capabilities. I don't know if it would be right to check it if you post it as an answer because it would only work for locally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe this is possible. However, it involves changing your global directory in R. This process is good if you're only going to be using the one directory for a while. To do this:

1. Go into RStudio
2. Select "Tools" -> "Global Options.."
   [image]
3. You should see something like the image above, then you can select "Browse..." in the red box which will bring up a folder selector, from here you can set your new permanent working directory
4. Once you've selected your folder, hit "Apply" and then "Ok"

After you've done this when you open your shinyApp with a `fileInput` the default should be the global path you just set.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from a portable version of R?

Comment: I mean, maybe from a command that I can run inside the application. This way is too static and the path couldn't be changes in runtime.

Comment: Maybe I missed something or someone who knows more can weigh in, but I've looked pretty hard and it doesn't seem like there is a way to do it using R code.